# Unable to write data to on premise SQL server using beam pipeline

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am trying to create a apache beam pipeline using python which reads data from CSV and stores the output data to on premise SQL server. I am not sure how to establish connection to SQL Server and write to the server. Can you please help me out here. Please let me know if any additional information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [JdbcIO.write](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.html)` to output the data to your SQL server. You will need to be sure the server is accessible to wherever your workers are running.